# Unable to send Data to the server with RuntimeException of handler inside thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httphandler, android-handler, android-toast

I have an activity in my android app where I am sending data to the server on button click. But when I click on Button, I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` I search on google but did not get solution.
Here is my code below:

```
try
    {
    HttpAsyncRegUser httpasync = new HttpAsyncRegUser();
    urlforpurchase = "http://"+ Constants.ip +"/venuscmsapp/services/purchase/insertpurchasedetails";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    httpasync.execute(new String[] { urlforpurchase });
    }
     catch(Exception excp){
        Log.e("Error fetching data : ", excp.getMessage());
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class HttpAsyncRegUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String str = null;
            try {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in HttpAsyncRegUser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String json;
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlforpurchase);
                 JSONObject puchaseJson = new JSONObject();

                 puchaseJson.put("productId", ITEM_SKU);
                 puchaseJson.put("userId", userId);
                 puchaseJson.put("productprice", price);
                 puchaseJson.put("productStartDate", productStartDate);
                 puchaseJson.put("productEndDate", productEndDate);
                 puchaseJson.put("paymentStatus",1);
                 puchaseJson.put("paymentDate", paymentDate);
                 puchaseJson.put("productType","SONG");
                 puchaseJson.put("status",1);

                 json = puchaseJson.toString();
                 System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  "+json);
                 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                 System.out.println("=========================  "+se);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in application/json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.e("post", "in application/json");
                 httpPost.setEntity(se);

                 httpPost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
                 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in application/json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in httpResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 str = inputStreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(" my Error", ""+e);
            }
            return str;
        }
        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return total;

        }
    }
```

Here is my logcat output below:

```
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at com.venus.browse.BrowseSongListActivity$HttpAsyncRegUser.doInBackground(BrowseSongListActivity.java:1005)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at com.venus.browse.BrowseSongListActivity$HttpAsyncRegUser.doInBackground(BrowseSongListActivity.java:1)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-18 12:03:40.851: W/System.err(1742):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-18 12:03:40.861: W/System.err(1742):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-18 12:03:40.861: W/System.err(1742):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-18 12:03:40.861: W/System.err(1742):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-18 12:03:40.861: W/System.err(1742):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-18 12:03:40.861: E/my Error(1742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: Try this :: HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);  httpasync.execute(urlforpurchase); Don't create a toast msg into the doInBackground process

Answer (score 1):

Toast messages are displayed on UI, So to display it from thread we have to put it into UIThread.

Replace your every `Toast` messages which is inside `doInBackground` function displayed as below,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in application/json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In doInBackground  method you can only perform background process and network operation. You can't update UI in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Toast` inside `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`.
Toast actually interact with UI and `doInBackground()` method runs in background(background thread) and it does not intract with UI.

That's why you are getting this error.
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from `doInBackground()` method

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in application/json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in httpResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

you can't update your UI in that method.

In `doInBackground()` you can only perform background process and network operation.